# working of the left join

Tags: sql

I have an example where in a table there is ID,NAme and M_if(managerID). I populated the table in the following manner

```
Id  Name M_id
1   A     2
2   B    NUll
3   C     1
4   D     3
5   E     2
```

Id is employee ID, Name and M_id is manager ID. In above example A's manager is 2(B), B doesn't have manager, C's manager is 1(A) and so on. I need to find out the names of the employees and their managers name. I have written the following query by doing permutations and combinations which gives me proper result but I am not able to comprehend how exactly the query(left join) is working. Please make me explain the concept.

```
SELECT (e.Name), ee.name FROM test.employee e
left join test.employee ee on ee.Id = e.M_id
order by e.Id;
```

result i get

```
A   B
B   
C   A
D   C
E   B
```

Please explain me the joint

Comment: you should use self join instead of left join.

Comment: @Prashant: Why? This works fine.

Comment: @Prashant,  : Please explain me how the left join is working.

Comment: DISTINCT can be removed... Besides, DISTINCT works on the whole selected rows, it's not a function on a column! "select distinct (a), b" eq. "select distinct a, b" eq. "select distinct a, (b)"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: @Prashant, self join? This is a self join (same table twice). Left outer join is to also get employees without managers!

Comment: Although your question perhaps isn't a perfect duplicate I believe you'll find the answer you're looking for in the post I linked.

Comment: @jarlh  : i got your point and i know he is using same table for left join but in this case its fine.

Answer (score 0):

two instances are there for same table as :

```
e
Id  Name  M_id
1   A     2
2   B    NUll
3   C     1
4   D     3
5   E     2

ee
Id  Name  M_id
1   A     2
2   B    NUll
3   C     1
4   D     3
5   E     2
```

according to your join condition `on ee.Id = e.M_id`

simply first row of  instance **e** will be selected because of left join and e.M_id will get compared to ee.Id and 2nd row will be selected from second instance of same table.

selection of data from both the table is as :

`e.Id  e.Name  e.M_id | ee.Id  ee.Name  ee.M_id
1      A       2     |  2      B       NUll
2      B       NUll  | 
3      C       1     |  1      A        2
4      D       3     |  3      C        1
5      E       2     |  2      B       NUll`

that is why it is showing

`A   B`